# Which software is recommended for building RAID in Windows 10?

Tags: raid, software-raid

We are running Windows 10 LTSC Enterprise. The workstation has 2 HDDs. I have created RAID1 with Storage Spaces. It is working well. But if I disconnect one of the disks, the notification comes only once, if I clear the notification bar on Windows by mistake, it never comes again.

I have tried SoftRaid, but if one of the disks is missing, it gives no notification, instead, it gives a notification when a disk is going to fail.

That's why I would like to know if anyone uses any RAID application in Windows 10? If yes, it would be nice to share it with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case it's better to use hardware RAID or at least Intel vROC (if your motherboard & CPU support them). They will give you required level of "autonomy", Storage Spaces need to have a "babysitter".

Comment: All RAIDs need a "babysitter" a.k.a. the monitoring and notification system, for the adminitrator to replace failed disks timely. RAID could not save you if you give it "autonomy". I've seen many cases how unmanaged RAID did not help the system to survive, complicating the recovery instead.

Comment: @ Nikita Kipriyanov

You never used Storage Spaces kludge, don’t you?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have used Storage Spaces, but its notification doesn't work as expected.
I have noticed that Intel vROC works only on Xeon processors, but we have a Workstation with Intel Core i7 12th Gen.
I tried to install Intel Rapid Storage on this machine, but Intel Rapid Storage is not compatible with Windows 10 LTSC version.
Which monitoring and notification system (babysitter) is recommended to use?

Comment: If you absolutely need to stick with the Storage Spaces you'll have to script health monitoring and recovery with PowerShell. This is a good place to start from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-states